# Event name conflicts and data out-of-bounds error in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, events, openzeppelin-contracts, import

I have been getting a weird `errored: Error: data out-of-bounds (length=0, offset=32, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.1.2)` error when testing contract functions in Remix, even though it goes through without revert. After debugging and stripping most of the logic, I found a minimal example to reproduce this problem:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.1.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.1.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Test is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("TEST", "TEST") { }
    
    function test() public {
        emit Transfer(address(0), address(0), 100);
    }
}
```

The `test()` call would produce an error

```
transact to Test.test pending ...
transact to Test.test errored: Error: data out-of-bounds (length=0, offset=32, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.1.2)
```

Looking closer, I can see that both OpenZeppelin's ERC20 and ERC721 contracts provide a `Transfer` Event. To verify this assumption, I commented out `//import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.1.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";` and the event emit works as expected. Because my contract uses ERC20 to instantiate an instance of a token so I need to import the definitions, but I am confused if this is a bug in Remix or by design a Solidity contract should not import two files with the same Event names? Is there any way to organize imports to get rid of this problem?

EDIT: There is no such issue when running the contract from hardhat, so I've filed a bug with Remix: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/issues/1242